# IF Statement to concatenate two strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I have a df with some account numbers and would like to add a "code" to those numbers if a condition is met.

If the account number is 2435 it should stay as 2435, if not it should add the code 8007 (for example, acct 5330 will be 53308007).

I tried writing an if statement, but it's not working. I get this error:
**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

```
if dist['Acct1']!='2435':
    dist['Acct1'] = dist['Acct1'] + code
else:
    pass
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where(ifcondtion, Account, Account+code)`
Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Acc':[2435,5330]})
```

Solution

```
 df['newacc']=np.where(df.Acc==2435, df.Acc, df.Acc.astype(str)+'8007')



 Acc    newacc
0  2435      2435
1  5330  53308007
```

Comment: Happy I could help